# Unable to open youtube link in another page from gridview ItemTemplate link button?

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I am binding a url`(www.Youtube.Com)` from back end to a grid view itemTemplate.When I click on this link button it does not redirects to youtube site.It open in a new page with my page url.I mean `(ViewVideo.aspx/youtube.com)`.how can avoid my page url from the begining?
My grid view code is

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" DataKeyNames="ID" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ID="grdAssignment" OnRowDataBound="grdAssignment_RowDataBound" GridLines="None" OnRowCommand="grdAssignment_RowCommand">
  <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField>
      <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="span3">
          <a href='<%#Eval("VideosLink") %>' target="_blank"  style="color:white"><i class="icon-film"></i> View Video</a>
        </div>
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

Now when I click on link button the url open in next page like `localhost:1256/ViewVide0/Youtube.com`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change the `<a>`  to `<asp:Hyperlink>`

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="span3">
               <asp:HyperLink ID="hl" runat="server" class="icon-film" Target="HyperLink" 
                              NavigateUrl='<%# String.Format("http://{0}", Eval("VideosLink").ToString()) %>' 
                              Text='View Video'></asp:HyperLink> 
          </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```